# QGIS scalebar shows a wrong scale

Tags: qgis, units

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does QGIS scalebar show a wrong scale?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/why-does-qgis-scalebar-show-a-wrong-scale)

I want the scale-bar in QGIS to be in meters/kilometers. Usually it's in degrees, but if I change it to meters it is displayed in cm. What's wrong? (Version is 1.7.4, coordinate system is WGS84) 
The units are wrong in the scale bar on the normal view and when I want to add a scale bar in the print composer, but the "measure"-tool gives correct numbers. It seems that one "cm" is 1km in reality.
I tried a range of different coordinate systems (projected and unprojected) but it's still the same. Part of the data comes from Open Street Maps part I collected with my GPS, so WGS84 should be correct, no?

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

This question has already been asked by an other user, but with no answer that solved my problem ([Why does QGIS scalebar show a wrong scale?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/why-does-qgis-scalebar-show-a-wrong-scale/31340#31340))